# Android soft keyboard in Chinese languages

Tags: android, localization, keyboard

I wanted to open soft keyboard in Chinese languages in my android application which supports localization. Can any one please help me out.

Comment: I think its not possible

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it. The Keyboard is separated app and you have no way to tell it what language you want. Except situation when a keyboard has api's to do it. Your only variant in to write your own internal keyboard.

Anyway, if a system locale is Chinese - user in most cases already have Chinese keyboard so you don't need to worry about it.